# errors when adding a microsoft login page

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using this step by step guide (https://blog.xamarin.com/authenticate-mobile-apps-using-microsoft-authentication-library/) to implement a microsoft login page to my app in which users have to login with a microsoft account. But I've gotten to step 3 and can't find a way to get rid of the errors.

Code in XAML:

```
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">

        <Button Text="Login" x:Name="LoginButton"/>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

Code in code behind (C#):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace RoseySports
{
    public partial class Login : ContentPage
    {
        public IPlatformParameters PlatformParameters { get; set; }

        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoginButton.Clicked += LoginButton_Clicked;

        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            App.ClientApplication.PlatformParameters = PlatformParameters;
            base.OnAppearing();
        }
        private async void LoginButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                AuthenticationResult ar = await App.ClientApplication.AcquireTokenAsync(App.Scopes);
                WelcomeText.Text = $"Welcome {ar.User.Name}";
            }
            catch (MsalException ex)
            {
                WelcomeText.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code in App.xaml.cs:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

namespace RoseySports
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static PublicClientApplication ClientApplication { get; set; }
        public static string[] Scopes = { "User.Read" };
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ClientApplication = new PublicClientApplication("your-app-id");
            var content = new Login();
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(content);

            MainPage = new Login_Page();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the screenshot with all the errors:[error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLlIo.jpg)[error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gOPo.jpg)[error 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqLwE.jpg)[error 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvYEq.jpg)

Also, could someone please explain to me where I should put this code in:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Login), typeof(LoginPageRenderer))]
namespace MSALForForms.iOS
{
   class LoginPageRenderer : PageRenderer
   {
      Login _page;
      protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
      {
          base.OnElementChanged(e);
          _page = e.NewElement as Login;
      }
      public override void ViewDidLoad()
      {
          base.ViewDidLoad();
          _page.PlatformParameters = new PlatformParameters(this);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a `using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;`

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro it gives me an error when I type that in: Using directive is unnecessary
The type or namespace name 'identitymodel' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

You should add `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` as you're missing this reference as per the screenshot errors. You can get this by added by NuGet package in VS.

1. Right Click on References and click on "Manage NuGet Packages"
2. On Browse tab, type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory' and install it by adding package.
3. Now use this namespace in your project. as - `using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;`

Comment: This got rid of the first error (error 4 in the pictures) but i'm still getting all the other ones

Comment: For others use - `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformParameters` and for WelcomeText you've to add label on login page

Comment: I get an error when i try putting it in. The error says: 'The type or namespace name 'PlatformParameters' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to add it by NuGet or reference in your solution

Comment: Which nugget package do i have to install? I already have the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory and typed in: using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;. It gives an error when adding platform parameters at the end

Comment: Apologies, you don't have to use this as namespace instead inherit this in your class like `public class YourClassName: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.IPlatformParameters`

Comment: Sorry if i misunderstood but I did what you said like so:                                                 public partial class Login : ContentPage , Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.IPlatformParameters. But i'm still getting the error (error 3 in the screenshot)

Comment: line 22, you can find the screenshots in my post

Comment: Inherit the same `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.IPlatformParameter` on App.xaml.cs

Comment: This is what the class in app.xaml.cs looks like now:     `public partial class App : Application, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.IPlatformParameters`
. But i'm still getting the error

Comment: I think you need to create a method inside App class with name ClientApplication and set property named PlatformParameters

Comment: I already have a method called ClientApplication and it looks like this: `ClientApplication = new PublicClientApplication(app-ID);` with app ID being my app ID and it's just under the `InitializeComponent();` . Should I change it, or just modify it, and I've got no idea how to modify it to set the property to PlatformParameters

Comment: just modify it and add property like you have - ClientApplication

Comment: not sure if what I did is correct : `ClientApplication = new PublicClientApplication("app-ID") && new platformParameters;` and I'm getting the same error as well as an error in app.xaml.cs due to the addition of `platformParameters`

Comment: Any Ideas cuz I'm still stuck on this